Maximize happiness in seating plan with cliques
Parameters of the problem:


There are $x$ tables with capacity 8, $y$ tables with capacity 6, and $z$ tables with capacity 4.

There are $8x+6y+4z$ people to seat.

There exist cliques that wish to sit together at the same table.

Not everyone is in a clique, and no one is in more than one clique.

Cliques vary in size, up to a maximum of 8. (No clique will be of size 9, for example, but there may be cliques of size 7.)

A person is defined as being happy if and only if their entire clique is sitting at the same table.

A person not in a clique is happy no matter what.



How can one figure out a seating plan to maximize happiness?
I don't think a greedy approach works here, because the optimal solution may involve splitting a big clique up in order to make everyone else happy.
I believe this is solvable with graph theory, but my knowledge in that area is very limited.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows. Let the cliques (including singletons) be $C_i$, so that $\cup_i C_i$ is the full set of people. Let table $j$ have capacity $b_j$. Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether clique $C_i$ is assigned to table $j$. The problem is to maximize $\sum_i \sum_j |C_i| x_{ij}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_{ij} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_i |C_i| x_{ij} &\le b_j &&\text{for all $j$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} assigns each clique to at most one table.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the table capacities.
The unassigned cliques can be split arbitrarily.
